# How to translate fortnight within a sentence?

Tags: english-to-german

There is one of Murphys rules: Dimensions  will  be  given  in  the  least 
usable units. Velocity, for example, will be given in Ångström per fortnight.

But there is no good German word for fortnight within this sentence: "Geschwindigkeiten werden zum Beispiel in Ångström pro Vierzehntagen angegeben" sounds odd in German. "Ångström pro Woche" is good German but less funny. But I don't like "Ångström pro zwei Wochen" too.

Another meaning but possible in German: "Ångström pro Vierteljahr" oder "Ångström pro Quartal". But in English, it can't be expressed precisely with one word only "Ångström per quarter of a year".

Comment: Just use a similarly absurd comparison, like _parsec per femtosecond_, for an example from the other end of the spectrum.

Comment: Also, didn't Murphy originally use **furlongs** instead of Ångström?

Comment: @Ingmar Entirely irrelevant footnote: Google's unit conversion mechanism does actually know *furlong per fortnight*

Comment: Sometimes you can't translate everything literally, and you have to pick the aspect you want to translate. The point of the text is clearly "unsuitable units of measurement", and it doesn't really matter if it's 14 days or not. So you pick a similar absurd measurement in the target language, and one that sounds natural. "Vierteljahr" is a good choice. It doesn't matter in this context that the actual value is different.

Comment: Vierteljahr is too comprehensible. Everyone knows what a Vierteljahr is. Take *Industrieminute*. It's well defined and is used, but hardly anyone not into the topic knows what it is. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrieminute

Comment: @Janka, every native English speaker knows what a fortnight is. It's not like furlongs.

Comment: When there is no fitting noun, but you want to keep the meaning  in one word, switch categories to adjectives. "Zweiwöchentliche Ångström" is approximately as absurd and obscure as the original expression.

Comment: _Ångström pro Halbmond_?

Comment: I do like the translation "Ångström pro Halbmond" it is one word and it is aproximately equal to a fortnight.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer could be easy by looking at the origin of [fortnight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortnight).

> The word derives from the Old English: fēowertyne niht, meaning "fourteen nights".

You could use:

> Geschwindigkeiten werden zum Beispiel in Ångström per Vierzehn Nächte
>   angegeben.

Using "Vierzehn Nächte" instead of "Vierzehn Tagen" brings across the curiosity of using a weird and unintuitive unit for measurement of time.

Answer (score 2):

> "Geschwindigkeiten werden zum Beispiel in Ångström pro Vierzehntagen angegeben" sounds odd in German.

I think it's okay to translate it like this. The whole purpose of the phrase is to sound odd because you actually should not give velocity in angstrom per fortnight but rather in meter per second or something similar. So the question is rather, does it sound overly odd? It doesn't and German speakers will understand "pro Vierzehntagen" equally well as "pro zwei Wochen".

In German, fortnight is used less often, so its translation may sound a bit odd. The natural unit is rather a single week, also indicated by the use of "two weeks" (zwei Wochen) to describe a fortnight.

I would have used different units for the indented meaning:

> "Velocity, for example, will be given in nanometer per week." - "Geschwindigkeiten werden zum Beispiel in Nanometer pro Woche angeben."

The idea is that these are still hilarious choices for units of velocity but closer to what people actually use, so it sounds less odd.

Comment: Nanometer is metric - Don't think that qualifies. Way too easy. "Klafter" sounds nice.

Comment: @tofro Indeed, Klafter sounds very nice and would work here.

Comment: Ångström is practically metric, i.e. as metric as bar. I don’t think, Ångström should have qualified in the first place ;)